# How can I use H2 database with laravel?

Tags: java, database, laravel, api, in-memory-database

I am currently in a project and we need for some reason use h2 database. I would like to do an api in this project and I want to use laravel, because it is a framework I know to use. But I can't found information about connecting h2 database with laravel. Anyone knows how to do that? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#introduction):

> Laravel makes interacting with databases extremely simple across a variety of database backends using either raw SQL, the fluent `query builder`, and the `Eloquent ORM`.

**Currently, Laravel supports four databases:**

```
MySQL 5.6+ (Version Policy)
PostgreSQL 9.4+ (Version Policy)
SQLite 3.8.8+
SQL Server 2017+ (Version Policy)
```

Reference:
[Laravel -> Database -> Introduction](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database#introduction)